# Pyspark struggling to understand why writeStream not writing to specified file

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

```
spark 3.3.2
python3.10
```

I have read the structure streaming documentation over [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) but I am still unable to get `writeStream` to actually persist any to disk for my use case. I am currently streaming data from a kafka topic, do some transformation, and write it to file. This is currently what I have:

```
# read data from topic
df = spark \
     .readStream \
     .format("kafka") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "my_broker:9092") \
     .option("subscribe", "my_topic") \
     .option("starting_offsets": "earliest") \
     .options("additional_options": {
                "maxOffsetsPerTrigger": 10000,
                "failOnDataLoss": "false"}) \
     .load()

# convert the byte array into a dict/Map object
df1 = df.selectExpr("cast(value as string) as jsonString").select(from_json(col("jsonString"), schema).alias("json"))

# write dataframe to disk
df1.writeStream \
   .foreachBatch(my_func)\
   .format("hudi")\
   .option("hoodie.table.name", "my_table")\
   .option("hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field", "precombine_key")\
   .option("hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field", "record_key")\
   .option("path", "/path/to/output/")\
   .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint/")\
   .trigger(processingTime="1 minutes")\
   .start()\
   .awaitTermination() 


def my_func(batch_df, batch_id):
    # process the JSON into tabular format and persist to disk
    processed_df = batch_df.select(
            col("json").getItem("payload").getItem("record_key").alias("id"),
            col("json").getItem("payload").getItem("precombine_key").alias("name"),
            explode(col("json").getItem("payload")).alias("keys")
        )
    return processed_df
```

when i run this, i do not see anything written to the specified directory `/path/to/output/` however, if i make the following changes to `writeStream` options and `my_func`:

```
# write dataframe to disk
df1.writeStream \
   .foreachBatch(my_func)\
   .trigger(processingTime="1 minutes")\
   .start()\
   .awaitTermination() 


def my_func(batch_df, batch_id):
    # process the JSON into tabular format and persist to disk
    processed_df = batch_df.select(
            col("json").getItem("payload").getItem("id").alias("id"),
            col("json").getItem("payload").getItem("name").alias("name"),
            explode(col("json").getItem("payload")).alias("keys")
        )
    processed_df.write\
                .format("hudi")\
                .option("hoodie.table.name", "my_table")\
                .option("hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field", "precombine_key")\
                .option("hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field", "record_key")\
                .option("path", "/path/to/output/")\
                .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint/")\
                .mode("append")\
                .save()
```

this works. But essentially i am just writing batches of dataframe to `path` and i am not actually "streaming" the data. What am i not understanding here? Using `write` within my `writeStream.foreachBatch` feels like I am defeating the purpose to using `writeStream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `foreachBatch` the write happens inside the function.

I think in your case `foreachBatch` is not necessary:

```
def my_func(df):
    # process the JSON into tabular format and persist to disk
    processed_df = df.select(
        col("json").getItem("payload").getItem("record_key").alias("id"),
        col("json").getItem("payload").getItem("precombine_key").alias("name"),
        explode(col("json").getItem("payload")).alias("keys")
    )
    return processed_df

df2 = my_func(df1)

query_handle = (
    df2
    .writeStream
    .format("hudi")
    .option("hoodie.table.name", "my_table")
    .option("hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field", "precombine_key")
    .option("hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field", "record_key")
    .option("path", "/path/to/output/")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint/")
    .trigger(processingTime="1 minutes")
    .start()
)
query_handle.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: can you explain why `forEachBatch` is not needed? From my understanding, i am streaming X records from kafka and spark is actually processing them in "micro-batches", so wouldnt i need `foreachBatch` to process these micro-batches?

Comment: You don't need it, please refer to the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch). Did you try the streaming query as it is in the example above?

Comment: thanks @boyangeor, i think i understand spark a litte bit more now and the above example does work. Thank you for the help!